# Python gdb support - /path/to/checkout

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, gdb

I am enabling gdb for Python support with Python 3.6.9 and gdb 8.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

In the document https://devguide.python.org/gdb/ it says, "When CPython is built you will notice a python-gdb.py file in the root directory of your checkout.  Read the module docstring for details on how to use the file to enhance gdb for easier debugging of a CPython process. To activate support, you must add the directory containing python-gdb.py to GDB’s “auto-load-safe-path”. Put this in your ~/.gdbinit file:  add-auto-load-safe-path /path/to/checkout"

On my distro (Ubuntu 18.04), gdb was installed by default, so I didn't build it from source with ./configure --with-python.  At the time of install I did not anticipate needing Python support.  When I search for  python-gdb.py using locate python-gdb.py it shows that  python-gdb.py does not exist.

My questions are:

1. Can I update my gdb installation to enable Python support?
2. What do I use for /path/to/checkout in the string "add-auto-load-safe-path /path/to/checkout."

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are running GDB v7 or above, you are already set. At least it worked for me on Raspbian 7.12